# Typing a thunk creator function in a React/Redux/Redux Toolkit application

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have two very similar features (AI "inpainting" and "outpainting" on a HTML canvas). They each have a tab in the app. Inpainting is working well and in use by the user base, and Outpainting is the current WIP.

The features have almost identical (but not trivial) components and state, and I want to share as much as possible of course.

I have this working but I am confused by the typing, and I'm also not sure if this is a great way to solve the issue.

Here is the set up:

To share reducer logic and initial state, I have wrapped `createSlice` as `createGenericCanvasSlice`, per the RTK guide: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#wrapping-createslice

```js
export const createGenericCanvasSlice = <
  Reducers extends SliceCaseReducers<GenericCanvasState>
>({
  name = '',
  initialState,
  reducers,
}: {
  name: string;
  initialState: GenericCanvasState;
  reducers: ValidateSliceCaseReducers<GenericCanvasState, Reducers>;
}) => {
  return createSlice({
    name,
    initialState,
    reducers: {
      ...genericCanvasReducers, // <--- the generic reducers below
      ...reducers,
    },
  });
};
```

The generic reducer object looks like this:

```js
export const genericCanvasReducers = {
  setTool: (
    state: GenericCanvasState,
    action: PayloadAction<InpaintingTool>
  ) => {
    state.tool = action.payload;
  },
  toggleTool: (state: GenericCanvasState) => {
    state.tool = state.tool === 'brush' ? 'eraser' : 'brush';
  },
  setBrushSize: (state: GenericCanvasState, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {
    state.brushSize = action.payload;
  },
  // etc
};
```

Then, each of the features get their own slice like this:

```js
const inpaintingSlice = createGenericCanvasSlice({
  name: 'inpainting',
  initialState: initialInpaintingState as GenericCanvasState,
  reducers: {
    // addition reducers here if needed
  },
});

const outpaintingSlice = createGenericCanvasSlice({
  name: 'outpainting',
  initialState: initialOutpaintingState as GenericCanvasState,
  reducers: {
    // addition reducers here if needed
  },
});
```

This works fine; I can dispatch the actions for slices created by `createGenericCanvasSlice`, but I have to know ahead of time if I want the inpainting action or outpainting action.

To solve this, I have generated thunks for each of the generic actions, which accept a second argument (the current tab name). Inside the thunk, check the tab name and dispatch the appropriate action to the appropriate slice.

```js
/**
 * Given the two possible actions, returns a thunk that accepts a payload and tab name
 * and dispatches the appropriate action to the appropriate slice.
 */
const createCanvasThunk =
  (inpaintingAction, outpaintingAction) =>
  (payload, activeTabName) =>
  (dispatch, getState) => {
    if (activeTabName === 'inpainting') {
      dispatch(inpaintingAction(payload));
    } else if (activeTabName === 'outpainting') {
      dispatch(outpaintingAction(payload));
    }
  };

/**
 * Creates an object with all the thunks, where the key is the action name. 
 */
export const canvasThunks = _.reduce(
  genericCanvasReducers,
  (thunks, _action, key) => {
    thunks[key] = createCanvasThunk(
      inpaintingActions[key],
      outpaintingActions[key]
    );
    return thunks;
  },
  {}
);
```

This works, but I cannot figure out the typing for the life of me, for `createCanvasThunk` and the `reduce` callback.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a much simpler solution. I made a new slice of state called `canvas` and gave it properties `inpainting` and `outpainting`, each of which have copies of the generic canvas state.

I gave the `canvas` slice another property `currentCanvas` which is `"inpainting" | "outpainting"`:

```js
export interface CanvasState {
  currentCanvas: ValidCanvasName;
  inpainting: GenericCanvasState;
  outpainting: GenericCanvasState;
}
```

I added logic to each reducer to use `currentCanvas` as an index for the base `canvas` slice, and then do the same logic.

```js
    setTool: (state, action: PayloadAction<InpaintingTool>) => {
      state[state.currentCanvas].tool = action.payload;
    },
```

The final step was to update all of my selectors. I exported a convenience selector from the new `canvasSlice` to simply get the current active canvas:

```js
export const currentCanvasSelector = (state: RootState) =>
  state.canvas[state.canvas.currentCanvas];
```

My selectors now look like this:

```js
const inpaintingBrushSelector = createSelector(
  [currentCanvasSelector, activeTabNameSelector, areHotkeysEnabledSelector],
  (currentCanvas: GenericCanvasState, activeTabName, areHotkeysEnabled) => {
    const { tool, brushSize, shouldShowMask } = currentCanvas;

    return {
      tool,
      brushSize,
      shouldShowMask,
      activeTabName,
      areHotkeysEnabled,
    };
  },
  {
    memoizeOptions: {
      resultEqualityCheck: _.isEqual,
    },
  }
);
```

We may wish to raise some pieces of state (e.g. the canvas brush radius) from the `inpainting`/`outpainting` level up to the base `canvas` level. Then we just remove the additional `currentCanvas` indexing from the appropriate reducer.

We may wish to have special handling inside the component depending on if we are on inpainting or outpainting. This will be handled by a simple conditional check within the component.

So the end result is very simple and we now only need to have special handling for the areas where the features diverge.

Comment: Great solution.  I have used this approach before myself.  I would say that the decision on whether to lift up states like brush radius depends on whether you want to keep the two states independent.  If a user sets their inpainting radius to 10 and then switches the tab to "outpainting", do you want to keep that same value?  If they set a value of 5 on the "outpainting" tab and then switch back to "inpainting", should the radius be the 10 that they set here previously? Or the 5 that they set more recently but on a different tab?

Comment: Your current setup supports totally independent states where changes to one will not impact the other.  A setup with raised properties supports apply changes to all canvases, regardless of where it was initiated.

Comment: @LindaPaiste Yeah, exactly as you suggested - we may consider "brush radius" as a user-level setting, while something like "inpainting mask" is a feature-level setting, and lift state accordingly for the user-level settings. 

Thanks for your comment, I'm more confident now that this is a good solution for the problem!